# How to find the name of the enclosing source file in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

At compile time, how to retrieve the name of the current source file (where the code is written) in scala 2.11?

Comment: What for you need it?

Let say you got some macro that will paste this string where you want, it will be in .class file. Evaluating name once on sturtup at Singleton is not a performance killer.

Comment: Sure, but since this information is clearly available to the compiler, and it is a constant, it seems more 'right' to retrieve it with a macro. It is still possible to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21893197/1670894 but apparently it has been deprecated with scala 2.11.

Comment: You want an object of the class named `CompilationUnit`. I've used it in compiler plugins, but don't quite remember how to get it or even if it's possible to get it from a macro. (possible == easily. You can cast the objects into their internal compiler representation, a very annoying task that made quit writing a few interesting macros).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the REPL, the name is console, but this shows that a position knows its source.

```
scala> import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.language.experimental.macros

scala> import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

scala> def f(c: Context): c.Tree = { import c._,universe._ ; Literal(Constant(c.enclosingPosition.source.file.name)) }
f: (c: scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context)c.Tree

scala> def g: String = macro f
defined term macro g: String

scala> g
res0: String = <console>
```

Comment: `c.macroApplication.pos.source.file.name`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a kinda hacky way that actually does the trick:

```
val srcFile = new Exception().getStackTrace.head.getFileName
println(srcFile)
```

Source: [How do I get the current script or class name in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129185/how-do-i-get-the-current-script-or-class-name-in-scala)

Comment: +1 for the pragmatic solution. Can one rely on that information being there? - I mean, what if you turn off debug info during compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can use @li-haoyi's excellent [sourcecode macro library](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode)

```
def foo(arg: String)(implicit file: sourcecode.File) = {
  println(s"this file is: '${file.getAbsolutePath}'")
}

foo("hello") // "this file is '/path/to/file'"
```

Plus, many other goodies like line number, variables names, etc.